# unityscript Closure Iterating through a Custom Class

Tags: for-loop, unity-game-engine, closures, unityscript

I have a custom class called SaveData that is made up of four strings.  I have an array of SaveData called loadEntries, and I want to iterate through each one and access the strings to compare them to something else.  I've done a lot of reading about closure in unityscript the past few days (there's obviously a lot of content around here), but I haven't found a way to handle this.  Most examples seem to only deal with printing out the value of each single entry, and don't work for my purposes.  Here's what I have so far, which won't compile (I understand why it won't, but I don't understand how to make it work):

```
function Update() {
  for (var entry : SaveData in loadEntries) {
    entry = extractData(entry);

    //logic with "entry" members
  }
}

function extractData(entry : SaveData) {
  return function(entry : SaveData) { var myEntry = entry; };
}
```

Do I need to use closure with each member of SaveData instead of the whole entry? Is this method even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to closure for the detailed answer, and he was correct in that it did not have any issues with scope.  However, I came back to this problem, and found out it arose because my custom class "SaveData" was made up of static declared strings.  Since they were static, only the final result was being saved.  I'll leave the question up in case anyone makes the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic template of code:

```
  // Create your class like this
  function SaveData(x1, x2, x3, x4) {

    this.string1 = x1; // Whatever value you need
    this.string2 = x2; // Whatever value you need 
    this.string3 = x3; // Whatever value you need
    this.string4 = x4; // Whatever value you need

  }

  // Now let us construct objects from SaveData class and insert them in array.
  var loadEntries = [];

  var firstInstance = new SaveData("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4");
  loadEntries.push(firstInstance);

  // we can directly push more objects without creating variables like this:
 loadEntries.push(new SaveData("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"));
 loadEntries.push(new SaveData("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"));
 loadEntries.push(new SaveData("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"));

  // Access like this in update function
  var myGlobalVar = "d1";
  for (var i = 0; i < loadEntries.length; i++) {

    var saveDataInstance = loadEntries[i];

    // let us log the instance on console to see it is correct
    console.log(JSON.stringify(saveDataInstance));

    if (saveDataInstance.string1 === myGlobalVar) {
       console.log("Found the instance we were looking for");

       // Other strings are 
       // saveDataInstance.string2
       // saveDataInstance.string3
       // saveDataInstance.string4
    }
  }
```

I don't see any need of closure in this case.

See a working demo here: http://jsbin.com/utezuq/1/watch

Comment: This method always references the final SaveData entry in the array, which is what led me to believe that closure was needed.

Comment: Are you implying that if you have 10 saveData instances in loadEntries array, you would like to compare them with each other to compute like sum, concat etc.

Comment: I'm trying to compare one of the variables within each SaveData instance to a global variable. If it's the same, then I want to access the remaining variables within that instance to do other computations.

Comment: This requirement would be met by the sample code above. No need on any closure. Updating the for loop to incorporate this. Bye!

Comment: I don't see why closure is needed either, and maybe it isn't.  But the fact remains that this method continues to reference only the last entry in the array, which is a good indicator of a closure problem.

Comment: I fail to get the last entry issue. Ain't all the entries at each index available in the for loop? (var saveDataInstance = loadEntries[i];) you may want to expand your the description of the issue. You may copy paste my answer in your question to explain.

Comment: I think I understood your assumption. Are you thinking that there is only one instance of SaveData available? I have modified the code above to demonstrate creation of instances and then setting them in array.